# Can I Vary on a custom header?

Tags: http, varnish, http-caching, distributed-caching

I'm bucketing User-Agents by device using something like [varnish-devicedetect](https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/devicedetect.vcl) and storing the result in `X-UA-Device` on the request and the response.

I've seen several [recommendations to vary on User-Agent](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details#dynamicserving).  Any reason not to vary instead on `X-UA-Device`?  Seems like it'd be nicer to downstream caches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `X-UA-Device` is not available on the client request or in any downstream proxys (it's generated inside Varnish) you have to vary on the raw `User-Agent` header.

Answer (score 0):

Although varying on `X-UA-Device` is incorrect for downstream caches, Varnish itself can still benefit from that optimization if you rewrite the Vary header in `vcl_deliver`:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.Vary) {
        set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary,
                                    "(?i)X-UA-Device",
                                    "User-Agent");
    }
}
```

This way, Varnish varies its cache on `X-UA-Device` and downstream caches vary on `User-Agent`.

In your question, you mentioned you were adding `X-UA-Device` to the *response* header as well as the request header.  In that case, the above suggestion will not work and you will instead need to send `Vary: User-Agent` unconditionally:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    set beresp.http.X-UA-Device = req.http.X-UA-Device;
    if (!beresp.http.Vary) {
        set beresp.http.Vary = "User-Agent";
    } elsif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "(?i)User-Agent") {
        set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", User-Agent";
    }
}
```

(I was not sure whether you were setting the `X-UA-Device` *response* header for the benefit of client-side scripts, or in the hope that it would be recognized by downstream caches.)

Comment: I think that's incorrect since `vcl_deliver` is called after Varnish itself has stored the object in cache. If you want to cache different versions of the same URL you should use `vcl_hash`

Comment: The idea is to have the application send `Vary: X-UA-Device` in the response header.  Varnish will store that version of the `Vary` header, and make its hit/miss decisions based on that version as well.  (Varnish _does_ honor the Vary header, so no additional `vcl_hash` logic is required.)  Rewriting the response header to `Vary: User-Agent` in `vcl_deliver` ensures any downstream caches will behave correctly.  (Note: I have tested this and confirmed it works with Varnish 3.0.5)

Comment: That's correct if the device detection is performed outside Varnish (in the application), if you perform the detection inside varnish (as in the original question) you should take care of the Vary header on `vcl_deliver` with something like: `if (resp.http.Vary) { set resp.http.Vary = resp.http.Vary + ",User-Agent"; } else { set resp.http.Vary = "User-Agent"; }`

Comment: It looks like the one detail I missed in the original question was that he was adding `X-UA-Device` both to the request _and_ the response.  I'll edit to make note of that.